# Transactions: IsolationLevel set to Serializable - is this correct?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, transactionscope

Could you please help me out confirming/disconfirming my doubts using Serializable isolationlevel.

I want to make sure that I've chosen a proper `IsolationLevel` for the following method `AddUserTournament`. Whenever this transaction is being executed, I want to be 100% sure, that `entity.seats` is up-to-date - preventing any other transactions from adding users concurrently.

Can I implement this using a more loose `IsolationLevel`, or does this seems as the proper way?

```
    public void AddUserTournament(Tournament entity, User user)
    {
        try
        {
            // Add the user to tournament. Do this with a snapshot-isolationlevel
            using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable))
            {
                try
                {
                    // Get all users and include their relations to tournament
                    entity =
                        _dbContext.Tournaments.Where(e => e.TournamentId == entity.TournamentId)
                            .Include(t => t.Users)
                            .FirstOrDefault();

                    // Get the user
                    user = _dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(e => e.UserId == user.UserId);

                    // Check if there are available seats in the tournament and if user exist amoung enrolled users
                    if (entity != null && entity.Seats > entity.Users.Count &&
                        entity.Users.All(e => user != null && e.UserId != user.UserId))
                    {

                        // Add user
                        entity?.Users.Add(user);

                        // Save changes
                        _dbContext.SaveChanges();

                        // Commit transaction
                        transaction.Commit();

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            throw new FaultException(new FormattedDbEntityValidationException(ex).Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: EntityFramework and ADO.NET are two very different technologies, don't tag them both as if the question was referring to both of them. As per your code, you are using EntityFramework so ADO.NET is totally irrelevant

Comment: Also simply your `if` logic or do it in steps... also entity is passed in and then override... doesn't make for good programming in my book.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not answering your question, but feel i should point out how to make it more readable.

Just showing how you could rewrite you 'if' into something readable.

```
//after you refactor it more you will see that this check is actually not needed.
if (entity != null)
{
    //Called entity but represents a Tournament
    //so the check is to see if the T has more seats than the current attending users
    if(entity.Seats.Count > entity.Users.Count)
    {
        //this was to check if the user is already in the attending users
        //if(entity.Users.All(e => user != null && e.UserId != user.UserId))

        var userInSeats = entity.Users.Where(x=>x.UserId == user.UserId).SingleOrDefualt();
        if(userInSeats == null )
        {
            // Add user
            entity.Users.Add(user);

            // Save changes
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();

            // Commit transaction
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

you would then see that the null check is not needed as this method should not be able to be called with no entity... i would call things what they are unless you are using generics which you aint here.